# Symbol Lookup Error: Combining Executable and Library on 64bits

Tags: c++, linker, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I want to make a dlopen on a library that uses executable's symbols. I'm compiling gdl-0.9 on a 64bits system and I'm building a library that gdl will use dlopen. The problem is that the library uses gdl code which will be at the executable and, even though I used the ***-Wl,--export-dynamic*** flag, the program crashes and prints:
gdl: symbol lookup error: ./two.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4EnvT6NParamEj

Here is how I've done things:

Compiled two.cpp as the shared lib two.so.

```
// two.cpp
#include "envt.hpp"

using namespace std;

template< typename T>
BaseGDL* two_fun_template( BaseGDL* p0)
{
  T* p0C = static_cast<T*>( p0);
  T* res = new T( p0C->Dim(), BaseGDL::NOZERO);
  SizeT nEl = p0->N_Elements();
  for( SizeT i=0; i<nEl; ++i)
    {
      (*res)[ i] = 2 * ((*p0C)[ i]);
    }
  return res;
}

extern "C" BaseGDL* two_fun( EnvT* e)
{

  SizeT nParam=e->NParam();
  if (nParam != 1) {
    cout << "TWO: Improper Number of Variables" << endl;
    return new DLongGDL( -1);
  }

  BaseGDL* p0 = e->GetPar( 0);//, "TWO");

  if( p0->Type() == DOUBLE)
    return two_fun_template< DDoubleGDL>( p0);
  else if( p0->Type() == FLOAT)
    return two_fun_template< DFloatGDL>( p0);
  else 
    {
      return new DLongGDL( -1);
    }
}
```

Used "Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS" pre-build of gdl.

```
$ gdl
GDL - GNU Data Language, Version 0.9
For basic information type HELP,/INFO
'GDL_STARTUP'/'IDL_STARTUP' environment variables both not set.
No startup file read.
GDL> linkimage,'TWO','./two.so',1,'two_fun'
GDL> print, "TWO Loaded"
GDL> print, two(1.0)
gdl: symbol lookup error: ./two.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4EnvT6NParamEj
```

So I figured the problem was upon executing this line: SizeT nParam=e->NParam();

Next I got the gld-0.9 source code, did the whole compilation with ***-Wl,--export-dynamic*** and the same error occurred.

Next I did the whole compilation with -m32 flag (force 32bits) and:

```
$ ../gdl32
GDL - GNU Data Language, Version 0.9
For basic information type HELP,/INFO
'GDL_STARTUP'/'IDL_STARTUP' environment variables both not set.
No startup file read.
GDL> linkimage,'TWO','./two.so',1,'two_fun'
GDL> print, "TWO Loaded"
GDL> print, two(1.0)
      2.00000
GDL>
```

So I guess this means its a 64bit problem, but why? I've searched a lot in the web and didn't find anything other then the ***-Wl,--export-dynamic***, maybe I didn't know how to look or something. Can anyone help?

Btw, this is what I get when running the "nm" util.

64bits:

```
$ nm two.so | grep NParam
                 U _ZN4EnvT6NParamEj
$ nm ../gdl64 | grep NParam
00000000006dc320 T _ZN4EnvT6NParamEy
```

32bits:

```
$ nm two.so | grep NParam
         U _ZN4EnvT6NParamEj
$ nm ../gdl32 | grep NParam
0830a6a0 T _ZN4EnvT6NParamEj
```

Comment: It looks like your headers disagree with the compiled library about the size of the `SizeT` typedef. Specifically, the library appears to be using a 64-bit return value, and `two.so` expects 32 bits. Try running the symbols from `nm` through `c++filt` to see what exact types `j` and `y` correspond to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_ZN4EnvT6NParamEj` is `EnvT::NParam(unsigned int)`
`_ZN4EnvT6NParamEy` is `EnvT::NParam(unsigned long long)`

So you should start with looking at how you include declaration of `EnvT`. You need to look at what type of an argument of NParam and find where it's redefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still can use the help, but for compiling the the two function and all the others for 64 bit you should add -DHAVE_64BIT_OS option to the g++ command. This way the preprocessor sets the right type for SizeT in typedefs.hpp.
So compiling will be

g++ -DHAVE_64BIT_OS -I/(path to gdl src) -c two.cpp -fpic

All the other commands stay the same.

Comment: I found out that after people pointed out the type differences. Thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the `nm` output it looks like the types are different - the executable has `_ZN4EnvT6NParamEy` while the library wants `_ZN4EnvT6NParamEj`. As you can see the last letter differs.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the difference but didn't know what it was